# how to solve this abstract ODES

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$$
\begin{equation}
\left\{
             \begin{array}{lr}
             \frac{\mathrm{d} x }{\mathrm{d} t}=p(t)x+q(t)y  \\
             \frac{\mathrm{d} y }{\mathrm{d} t}=q(t)x+p(t)y\\ 
             \end{array}
\right.
\end{equation}
$$
p(t),q(t) is continuous in $$\lbrack a,b\rbrack$$.

I am a rookie in ODE, I have tried to use Picard's method to approach the answer, but I cannot find an initial value.

Comment: You don't find the initial value, it's given at the start.

Comment: Presumably the second term is $y$ in both formulas. Consider the sum and difference of both equations to get easily solvable scalar equations.

Answer (score 2):

Let $u = x + y$. Then $$\frac {du}{dt} = (p+q)u$$ which is easily solved.
Once you've found $u$, you can solve
$$\frac {dx}{dt} + (q-p)x = qu$$
to find $x$ and $y = u-x$.